# ASP.NET MVC brakes JS call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the string with javascript call which is bound to HTML Select event:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DropDownName, Model.ItemsForView, new { onchange = "someMethod('someArgumentValue')" })
```

which is rendered to the following code:

```
onchange="someMethod(&#39;someArgumentValue&#39;)"
```

Is there any way to make ' symbol render "as is"?

Comment: You may want to consider wiring up your events dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use unobtrusive javascript:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DropDownName, Model.ItemsForView, new { id = "foo" })
```

and in a separate `.js` file:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').change(function() {
        someMethod('someArgumentValue');
    });
});
```

There are at least two benefits:

- You are not mixing script and markup
- Markup is reduced and scripts are cached by the browser

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go. Note that it brings a dependency of jQuery to the mix, but this is a good thing :-)

Comment: I will reimplement it to unobtrusive js eventually... but now I need quick and dirty solution. I hoped there is one...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DropDownName, Model.ItemsForView, new { onchange = @"someMethod('someArgumentValue')" })
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DropDownName, Model.ItemsForView, new { onchange = "someMethod(\'someArgumentValue\')" })
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.DropDownName, Model.ItemsForView, new { onchange = "someMethod(\\\"someArgumentValue\\\")" })
```